# Issues while running Java Tableau Extract API sample program

Tags: java, linux, tableau-api

I am trying to run the 'TableauSDKSample' java program on an Amazon EMR machine running Linux (64 bit) using my own custom jar. When I try to run my program, I get the following error:

```
A fatal error occurred while creating the extract:
Hyper Server did not call back on the callback port: process = 30320
Printing stack trace now:
com.tableausoftware.TableauException: Hyper Server did not call back on 
the callback port: process = 30320
at com.tableausoftware.hyperextract.Extract.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.samsung.tabluea.TableauSDKSample.createOrOpenExtract(TableauSDKSample.j
ava:119)
at com.samsung.tabluea.TableauSDKSample.main(TableauSDKSample.java:234)
Exiting now.
```

Here's what I did:

1. I downloaded the Extract API for C/C++/Java (64-bit) (.tar.gz file)
2. I untarred the above file in *install-dir* using tar -xvzf
   extractapi-linux-x86_64-10-5-0.tar.gz
3. I created a jar using maven
   for my very simple custom project having only one file
   TableauSDKSample.java
4. To install the shared libraries, I copied all
   the files from
   *install-dir*/hyperextractapi-cpp-linux-gcc-x86_64-release-2017.4.0.127.r9c0f968e/lib64/tableausdk/
   to /lib64/. By doing this, I avoid setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   explicitly. See this for details: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/install-a-unix-including-linux-shared-library
5. Then I tried to run my program using
   the following command:

   ```
   sudo java -cp install-dir/hyperextractapi-cpp-linux-gcc-x86_64-release-2017.4.0.127.r9c0f968e/lib64/tableausdk/:install-dir/hyperextractapi-cpp-linux-gcc-x86_64-release-2017.4.0.127.r9c0f968e/lib64/tableausdk/Java/:/path/to/my/custom-jar.jar fully.qualified.MainClass
   ```

   (where my main class is TableauSDKSample)

There is definitely no issue with the code as it is running on my local system where I use Eclipse IDE to run it. What am I doing wrong?